# Detecting the form move event from within a child control

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I am creating a user control where when a user clicks a button a popup window will show up with information.  The popup window is driven by a toolStripDropDown so when it shows up it does 2 things

1. Does not move the other controls on the form around but displays over them
2. That it can show the details outside the bounds of the user control itself without having to reserve the space ahead of time

Here is some code

```
Public Class Popup
Private treeViewHost As ToolStripControlHost
Private Shadows dropDown As ToolStripDropDown

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim treeView As New TreeView()

    treeView.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    treeViewHost = New ToolStripControlHost(treeView)
    treeViewHost.Padding = New Padding(6)

    dropDown = New ToolStripDropDown()
    dropDown.AutoClose = False
    dropDown.AutoSize = True
    dropDown.BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon
    dropDown.Items.Add(treeViewHost)
End Sub

Public Sub ShowDropDown()      
    If dropDown.Visible = False Then
        dropDown.Show(Me, Button1.Left + Button1.Height + 5, Button1.Top)
    Else
        dropDown.Close()
    End If

End Sub    

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ShowDropDown()
End Sub

Private Sub Popup_Move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Move, Button1.Move
    If (dropDown IsNot Nothing AndAlso Button1 IsNot Nothing AndAlso dropDown.Visible) Then
        dropDown.Left = Button1.Left + Button1.Height + 5
        dropDown.Top = Button1.Top
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

And here is the init of the control

```
'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'Button1
    '
    Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(4, 4)
    Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(27, 23)
    Me.Button1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Popup
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
    Me.Name = "Popup"
    Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 35)
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
```

Now my issue is as the form moves or resizes the Tooldropdown does not move relative.  I understand that. When I try to capture the move event of the user control that event does not fire when the entire form moves.  There has to be something I can capture because the controls in the container of the form move relative, what drives that?  I tried wndproc but nothing fires during form move unless the form is repainted.

Thank you

Current code is in VB but I can handle both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this did it

```
 AddHandler Me.ParentForm.Move, AddressOf Popup_Move
```

In the load event.  I had to do it in the load event because ParentForm is not available earlier.  I also tried the ParentChange event but that did not work if I was in a Panel

```
Me.Parent would equal Panel but
Me.Parent.Parent would equal nothing (also .ParentForm was Nothing)
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# :

Move and Resize events:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move.aspx

Just add in your .Designer.cs

```
this.Move +=new System.EventHandler(Form_Changed);
this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(Form_Changed);
```

I don't know if its possible in VB.

Answer (score 2):

You can suscribe Parent Events with **AddHandler**

But you do it on Parent_changed events. Note that Parent is nothing until control is added to other control or Form.

```
Private Sub GantCtl_ParentChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ParentChanged
   Dim mParent = DirectCast(Parent, Form)
   AddHandler mParent.KeyDown, AddressOf Parent_KeyDown
   AddHandler mParent.MouseWheel, AddressOf Parent_MouseWheel
   AddHandler mParent.Resize, AddressOf parent_Resize
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have a toolstrip that needs to move in conjunction with the form whenever it is moved by the user or some event that you control. If that be the case, I would do something like the following:

```
'Function within the form that is being moved and governs the location of the ToolStrip
Private Sub Form1_LocationChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.LocationChanged
    'lastLocation is a global variable that is reset every time the form is moved
    Dim offsetX As Integer = lastLocationX.X - Location.X
    Dim offsetY As Integer = lastLocationX.Y - Location.Y
    ToolStrip1.show(lastXcoord - offsetX, lastYcoord - offsetY)
    lastLocation = Location
End Sub
```